# Thumbnail grid is displayed in a column

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to create a grid of several thumbnail images but I have the same problem, which is that my images are in columns. Indeed, I have one image per line, whereas I want as many as possible.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:
https://codepen.io/pjhooker/pen/lFuDK

```
    <div>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div
```

The problem is that even with this code my images remain in columns underneath each other

Here's what I have in my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="hex-row even">
                <Hexagon v-for="n in 7" v-bind:key="n"/>
            </div>
            <div class="hex-row">
                <Hexagon v-for="n in 7" v-bind:key="n"/>
            </div>
            <div class="hex-row even">
                <Hexagon v-for="n in 7" v-bind:key="n"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 300px;">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="img in images" v-bind:key=img>
                    <v-img max-width="48px" max-height="48px" v-bind:src=img />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.hex-row {
    clear: left;
}
.hex-row.even {
    margin-left: 53px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;

  transition: all .3s ease;
}
</style>

<script>
import Hexagon from './Hexagon'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        images : [url, url, url...]
    }),
    components: {
        Hexagon,
    }
}
</script>
```

With the code above, I have images of 48px * 48px that are arranged one below the other.

I want the images to be next to each other. As soon as there is no more space on the line, the sequence continues on the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap` to the parent container

Here is a similar pen using `div` elements instead of `li`
https://codepen.io/chrismclarke/pen/ExYZxbG

Answer (score 0):

Apply following code in your CSS.

```
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```